# SQL Server Replication and Recovery Model

Tags: sql-server, replication, transaction-log, recovery-model

In SQL Server for Replication when recovery model is not very important then how it saves the transactions and also keeps the secondary instance in sync?

I tried to check on MSDN and found [the following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/administration/frequently-asked-questions-for-replication-administrators?view=sql-server-2017):

> Replication functions properly using any of the recovery models:
>   simple, bulk-logged, or full. Merge replication tracks change by
>   storing information in metadata tables. Transactional replication
>   tracks changes by marking the transaction log, but this marking
>   process is not affected by the recovery model

but I didn't get the concept for SIMPLE Recovery Model. And if the T-logs gets copied before checkpoint then what if someone manually executes checkpoint?

Answer (score 4):

Even in simple recovery, configuring a database for Transactional Replication prevents log reuse until the Log Reader has consumed the log records and marked them as read.